# Can ajax make a web application stateful?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stateless, stateful

Ajax can return the information on a browser without the need of a refresh. Does it mean it stores ID in a session/ stateful behaviour? I don't see any change in the URL in a web application which is based on Ajax. Example I am looking at is - http://evolvingweb.github.io/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.html. I am trying to compare an UI developed in ASP.NET MVC which is stateless vs. when a UI developed in javascript framework with ajax

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. From [Http RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/Specs.html):

> The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is an application-level
>   protocol for distributed, collaborative, hypermedia information
>   systems. It is a generic, stateless, protocol which can be used for
>   many tasks beyond its use for hypertext, such as name servers and
>   distributed object management systems, through extension of its
>   request methods, error codes and headers. A feature of HTTP is the
>   typing and negotiation of data representation, allowing systems to be
>   built independently of the data being transferred.

Ajax isn't as you are thinking about: 
From [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/):

> AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.
>
> AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.
>
> AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small
>   amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it
>   is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole
>   page.
>
> Classic web pages, (which do not use AJAX) must reload the entire page
>   if the content should change.

[ASP.NET State Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can be done using Cookies, Session, [Browser Cache](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) (HTML5 provide Browser DataBase for Caching Today), Profile, SQL Server Cache, QueryStrings, HiddenFields.

There's a new trend to build Web Applications that are responsive to user, [SPA](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/) (Single Page Application) that provides a awesome user experience using Ajax and MVVM frameworks build in JavaScript.

The guy behind [SPA](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/), using Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, is [Jonh Papa](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/).

Comment: Hi Fals! Thanks for your response! When a web application uses AJAX technique, does it make it stateful?

Comment: Still stateless, did you read the awnsear? the part that talks about AJAX says what AJAX is!

Comment: when you mentioned "by exchanging small amounts of data" - Could you elaborate that? How does it exchange the data? It doesn't pass the ID in a URL, so how does it exchange it?

Comment: That means: you will call something in the server (mostly like WebService, RestFul Service) to give you a portion of HTML, or JSON, or XML and then use this to display data to the client in the browser! You can use JavaScript to manipulate this data, change HTML DOM to give new HTML or Changed HTML to display it. That means, client will see only partial updates in the browser, not a full page reaload.

Comment: so AJAX always communicate with web server though web services?

Comment: No, Web Services or the Server that have the App. If know something about Asp.Net MVC, you will remenber PartialViews, thats HTML, you cam consume it using Ajax!

Answer (score 0):

I would say, yes, it does make a page stateful.

As I understand it you could: 
set a javascript variable `myGlobal = "current value"`, 
then remove e.g., "`<div id='content'>`" and replace it with new content, 
and the variable `myGlobal` could still be used and its value would remain.

That seems like state to me.